# This script does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saved this jQuery Script I have in notepad and saved it as 'test.HTML' and does not seem to be working correctly. It works perfectly in jsfiddle but not as a .HTML file. If anyone can help, that will be great.

Here is the working script in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/28/

Here is the script that's not working once saved as .HTML - http://goo.gl/WXwQ3

Answer (score 3):

You did not add jQuery library (jsfiddle add it automatically for you in their test page)